# How to select the farthest point on the x-axis?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools, grease-pencil

I have a lot of these curves in different shapes. Finding the most convex points along the axes by eye is not an option, you need absolute precision.

Maybe someone can suggest a script that would select the most distant point on any axis. Or maybe there is already a built-in command in Blender to do the same thing.

If it would be easier to do the task with Mesh rather than Grease Pencil - you could convert curves to Mesh as well, no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* deselect everything and press <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to switch to *Python Console*, then paste the below oneliner:

`axis=0; C.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'; max((p for s in C.editable_gpencil_strokes for p in s.points), key=lambda p:abs(p.co[axis])).select = True;`

(using inline formatting on purpose because it's a long line)

After pasting and pressing <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> the view should switch back to *Viewport 3D* and the furthest point on chosen axis (`axis=0` for $x$, `axis=1` for $y$, `axis=2` for $z$) should be selected:

[image]

Comment: Argh I'll never understand nested for loops syntax

Comment: @Gorgious it seems like it should be reversed to resemble the ordering in a human language, but it's simple when you think in terms of normal loops: `for s in C.editable_gpencil_strokes: for p in s.points:` - this is how you would normally loop, and you put it in the same order to the comprehension/generator, just without the colons, and at the very start you add the evaluated result for each step (here just `p`).

Comment: Hehe thanks for the explanation. Every time I think I understand but when I stumble upon having to do it from scratch a few months later I always get it wrong. Maybe with this method it'll stick :p

Comment: +1 ... but .. is this compression over clarity? Not my area.  I defer to your greater experience. Is there a more readable way of expressing this, though? (A bit rich, from me, I used to script Perl quite a lot)

Comment: @RobinBetts it is "compression over clarity", just because it's a shift+f4 technique, could write an operator, or if OP wants to select in all gpencil objects, layers, frames, could loop through them, but for now OP hasn't commented.